# How to use promise with map() in react native

Tags: typescript, react-native, promise, jsx

I'm new to React Native and I'm learning it.
I would like to use Promise with map(), It's not very clean for me and I've got an error :

> "TypeError: Type Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.lessons.map')"

in ExploreScreen

```
interface IProps {
  navigation: NavigationScreenProp<any, any>;
}

interface IState {
  lessons: ILesson | [];
}

export class ExploreScreen extends Component<IProps, IState> {    
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {lessons: []}
  }
  public async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({lesson: await ExploreData.getData()});
  }   
  public render() {
    let block
    if(this.state.lessons === null) {
      block = <View><Text>Loader</Text></View>;
    } else {
      block = (
        <ScrollView>
          {this.lessons.map((lesson: ILesson) => (
            <LessonListItem
              key={lesson.id}
              lesson={lesson}
            />))}
        </ScrollView>
      );
    }
    return (
      <View>
        {block}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In ExploreData

```
export class ExploreData extends CoreData {
  public static async getData(id: string): Promise<ILesson[]>{
    await ExploreData.wait();
    const data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
      data.push(CoreData.getLesson());
    }
    return data;
  }
  private static wait(): Promise<{}> {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000);
    });
    return promise;
  }
}
```

If someone can help me It's would be very nice. Thank you

Comment: `this.lessons` does not exist, it should be `this.state.lessons`

Comment: Typo `this.lessons.map` -> `this.state.lessons.map` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer the error is disappear but nothing appear there are not lessons :/

Comment: Second mistake: in componentDidMount you are setting `this.setState({lesson: ...}`, which should be `this.setState({lessons: ... `}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several typos in your code:

```
export class ExploreScreen extends Component {    

  public async componentDidMount() {
    // Typo here:
    this.setState({lessons: await ExploreData.getData()});
  }   
  public render() {
    let block
    if(this.state.lessons === null) {
      block = <View><Text>Loader</Text></View>;
    }else{
      block=(<ScrollView>
      {
      // Typo here:
      this.state.lessons.map((lesson: ILesson) => (
        <LessonListItem
          key={lesson.id}
          lesson={lesson}
        />
        ))
      }
    </ScrollView>
      );
    }
    return (
      <View>
        {block}
      </View>
    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out `this.lessons` should be `this.state.lessons`